# local debug azure function fail with error - Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I try to local debug the azure function, but got issue. Actually I just follow the instruction to build and tested with below link, but not work.

The instruction is here [Debug the Azure Functions Python code locally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/tutorial-vs-code-serverless-python-04?tabs=powershell), and I did not modified the code at all.

While I try to run debug, it pop up error.

> Executing task: .venv\Scripts\activate ; func host start
>
> Found Python version 3.8.6 (py).
>
> Azure Functions Core Tools Core Tools Version:       3.0.3160 Commit
> hash: 00aa7f43cc5c5f15241b5e6e5363256f19ceb990 Function Runtime
> Version: 3.0.14916.0
>
> **Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')**
>
> Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

I have no idea what's wrong after I search lots of topic in GitHub or stackoverflow. Finally I remove the azure function extensionBundle in the **host.json** as a workaround.

Did anyone encounter the same issue with me?

Below is my environment:
Windows 10
Python 3.8.6
Function Core Tools Version:3.0.3160
python packages azure-functions 1.50

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try to open the `Command Palette (F1)`, select the `Python: Select Interpreter` command, and then select the virtual environment in the local `.venv` folder

[image]

Or you can change `host.json`, `extensionBundle` requires a higher version.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I not test yet but final I follow the document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=windows%2Cpython%2Cbash#explicitly-install-extensions to Explicitly install extensions, which work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Another thing why local debugging might not work is low internet connection.
I had such a case with same "Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')" error when trying to work from a hotel with bad (low speed and not stable) internet connection.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your Azure Function Core Tools version.

I was on [4.0.3971](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/releases/download/4.0.3971/func-cli-4.0.3971-x64.msi), the function started fine.

Upgraded to 4.0.4670 (latest at the time), got the same error as you did.

Reverted to 4.0.3971, worked fine.

Comment: How are you finding older versions? I'm looking in the CDN but not finding .3971.