# Java Azure Functions throws error during running locally - A host error has occurred during startup operation

Tags: java, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime, azure-functions-core-tools

I have created a azure function in java created Using Command line by following below given Microsoft guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-cli-java

I have followed all the steps, but while running function locally using command as attached in below screenshot.
[image: Running function locally]

I am getting the following error:

[image: error]

Anyone please help me in resolving the above error to run the azure function locally.

Thanks & Regards,
Preethi H R

Comment: try uninstall and install again of Azure Function Core tools. Also, if you are connected to corp network, disconnect and try on home or private network, similar [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azurefunctions/issues/1731)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- This might be the known bug in the azure function extension bundle. So a work around for that, in your project remove the following code from the `host.json` file

```
"extensionBundle": {

"id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",

"version": "[3.*, 4.0.0)"

}
```

[image]

- Then restart the project with the following command

```
 mvn -e  azure-functions:run
```

[image]

Refer the work around given in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65410908/local-debug-azure-function-fail-with-error-value-cannot-be-null-parameter-p#:%7E:text=in%20the%20host.json%20as%20a%20workaround.)

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply. Indeed the solution helped me in deploying the Java function locally. Following the same tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-cli-java I am trying to deploy into azure but I am getting following error

Comment: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.microsoft.azure:azure-functions-maven-plugin:1.19.0:deploy (default-cli) on project acc-functions: load Function app (acc-functions-20220908124034280): Status code 403, "{"error":{"code":"AuthorizationFailed","message":"The client 'preethi.h.r@accenture.com' with object id 'b0a578e0-4c3a-40d3-b487-41f846871419' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Web/sites/read' over scope '/subscriptions/8aea60a3-ae35-41be-ab84-184c32be829f/resourceGroups/java-functions-group/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/acc-functions-20220908124034280'

Comment: this is an auth issue check your subscription whether you have auth to do this

Comment: Do I require any specific permissions for deployment? and will the deployment create only new resources? Cannot we make use of existing resources for deployment?

Comment: permissions are related to the role that is assigned to you  refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles

Comment: Sure will check on the link. Thank you.